# Copy matching elements under one group element

Tags: xslt-2.0

I have a flat xml and I need to copy all matching elements under one element.

In input xml there are title elements which can randomly appear in xml. I want to put them under one element. Any help?

Input:

```
<root>
   <element>
      <para>Text 11.</para>
      <para>Text 22.</para>
    </element>
   <title number="1">
      <title.block>Title1</title.block>
      <para>Text 33.</para>
      <para>Text 44.</para>
   </title>
   <title number="2">
      <title.block>Title2</title.block>
   </title>
   <element1>
      <para>Some Text</para>
   </element1>
   <title number="3">
       <title.block>Title2</title.block>
       <para>Text 55.</para>
   </title>
   <result>
      <para>Some Text</para>
   </result>
</root>
```

desired output is:

```
<root>
   <element>
      <para>Text 11.</para>
      <para>Text 22.</para>
    </element>
    <title.group>
   <title number="1">
      <title.block>Title1</title.block>
      <para>Text 33.</para>
      <para>Text 44.</para>
   </title>
   <title number="2">
      <title.block>Title2</title.block>
   </title>
   <title number="3">
       <title.block>Title2</title.block>
       <para>Text 55.</para>
   </title>
   </title.group>
   <element1>
      <para>Some Text</para>
   </element1>
   <result>
      <para>Some Text</para>
   </result>
</root>
```

Comment: You are much more likely to get help if you include the code you have tried so far and say something about what it is doing wrong.  See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: We are not a "Do my homework" service.

Comment: Sorry. I tried out different XPath combinations but nothing worked for me so didn't know which one to add here. But will keep in mind next time. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply write a template for the first `title` that creates the group and copies that title and all following siblings into the group:

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="root/title[1]">        
        <title-group>
            <xsl:copy-of select="., following-sibling::title"/>
        </title-group>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="root/title[position() gt 1]"/>

</xsl:transform>
```

http://xsltransform.net/a9Giwu